# Is winterbash-2015 coming?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

My daughter is curious as to whether kittens and other cute drawings on top of SO avatars are coming back this year?

Comment: sure... "your daughter" ;) (joke btw :P)

Comment: http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Patrice LOL :) :) :) Fine, I am curious too, but I like the process of figuring out how you get secret hats more than I like the hats themselves.

Comment: ...asking for a friend

Comment: Explain please, LINK me! I'm new and I don't know what winterbash is

Comment: I'm sure someone spent a lot of time coming up with the script for those little people running around at http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/ but I have no idea what the hell they're spelling out. I also have a strange urge to fly a helicopter around to try and pick them up.

Comment: @j08691 See [Understanding the winterbash-2015 countdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311754/understanding-the-winterbash-2015-countdown?lq=1), which is also linked on the right side of this post.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton See: http://stackexchange.com/promos/15/winter-bash-2014

Comment: @j08691 It takes some watching: eventually I figured out the winterbash2015.stackexchange.com countdown shows a number that changes every minute, and at 8:52 PM Mountain time it was at 12128,  so I'm guessing something happens in 12128/60/24 hours (or 8 days, 10 hours, and 8 minutes) from now...

Comment: Does winter bash include the breaking rocks? I forgot. My fingers need the exercise.

Comment: Keep in mind that the hats will be gone after the show, if this year is the same as the past ones.

Comment: @peeskillet no. unicoin mining was an April 1 event.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes.

It will start on December 14 and end on January 3.

Source: The email notifying moderators of the event.

Comment: Thank you Yannis. Can't make heads or tails of the animated countdown tbh.

Comment: You can also ask [a little bot.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25955419#25955419)