# Understanding the winterbash-2015 countdown

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

Can someone please explain the [animation](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)?

According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311745/is-winterbash-2015-coming), the lovely hats are supposed to start on December 14. Today is the 4<sup>th</sup>, why 13:04 is being displayed? Or is it something else? These little guys confuse me.

[image: WUT]

Comment: So 13184, not 13:04.

Comment: Fun fact: The little men are the souls from deleted accounts.

Comment: @Will Funny, I would think there would be more. Unless most deleted accounts have no souls? (I would believe it.)

Comment: The number 1 appears as two disjoint segments, because the algorithm uses [seven-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display) to represent numbers, allowing some distance between the segments. One can see small gaps in other digits, but with 1 it is particularly noticeable, to the point that it can be confused for `:`.

Comment: Can't we add more people? The numbers would be better understood, and more deleted accounts would be accounted for.

Comment: This sort of completely pointless nonsense that is neither funny nor interesting should be deleted from the site.

Comment: I want to offer a 500-rep bounty on this question to express my extreme confusion as to what the hell those people are trying to spell out! ...Except this isn't meta.SE, so, I won't ;-)

Comment: @JoeBlow Wow, did you get out of bed on the wrong side this morning? )

Comment: @JoeBlow more like *Joe Schmo*

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's a countdown clock in minutes, until the <strike>nonsense</strike>...err...fun of hats begins!

Comment: Inventive but not very useful. Could it be tweaked to show day, hours and minutes instead?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure we would make an adjustment for this year's countdown, maybe in the future.

Comment: I like it, very cool. Wouldn't worry about making it more "useful", after all it's just a bit of fun. Nice job.

Comment: Any chance to get that script released? I'd really like to tinker with it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid you mean [this](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/countdown.js?v=73c502a07616) ?

Comment: @Thomas, yes, but the un-deflated version of it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid easy, see [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/304f2b515be3f46b0714/raw/83db1258bf7c432c181b7dbfef66d428e0942f8b/WinterBash)

Comment: @Thomas `function i(e, t, n, i, a, s, r, h)` isn't really helpful for understanding the code :|

Comment: @Will Comments are for the weak!

Comment: When scientists write code.