# Are we close to Winterbash 2016?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I wonder, is Winterbash 2016 coming? Any chance it will start sooner than December 14?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nice count down

Comment: I miss those creepy tiny people from last year countdown.

Comment: Ok, unicorn is there, but what about waffles????

Comment: the unicorn isn't visible at my browser resolution

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, Winterbash 2016 is coming: https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/

No, it won't be here by the 14th. The event starts 2016/12/19, to run until 2017/01/08.

Comment: Really liking that countdown animation.

Comment: I really love how this year's one is so much more useful than last year's http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311754/understanding-the-winterbash-2015-countdown?rq=1#comment280256_311757; or how to troll @Lightness like pros

Comment: Downvoted in order to obtain hat.